# Aliases inside of an imported module don't work within a local Nuxt module

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

My situation is as follows. I'm building a nuxt module for discord integration. I need to iterate through the file system and import files from the `./server/discord/events` folder, and then bind these to `client.on(, (...args) => event.execute(args));`

The problem is files inside of the `./server/discord/events` folder, error out when I try to import from local modules using aliases [ex. `import {utilityHelper} from '~/server/utils/'`] (I'm forced to use relative paths, which is not optimal, and in some cases makes things I'm trying to do impossible).

Within a Nuxt module, how do I set it up so I can do this?

```
<!--- module.ts --->

import {
  defineNuxtModule,
  addTemplate,
  addServerPlugin,
  createResolver,
  useLogger,
} from "@nuxt/kit";

import { genDynamicImport, genImport } from "knitwork";

import { GatewayIntentBits, Events } from "discord.js";
import { defu } from "defu";
import useDiscord from "./client";
import { fdir } from "fdir";

interface DiscordEvent {
  /**
   * Event name
   */
  name: Events;
  /**
   * Boolean denoting whether to execute the event only once.
   */
  once: boolean;
  /**
   * Event handler.
   */
  execute: Function;
}

interface ModuleOptions {
  /**
   *
   */
  intents?: GatewayIntentBits[];
}

const PACKAGE_NAME = "nuxt3-discord-bot";

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: PACKAGE_NAME,
    configKey: "discord",
  },
  defaults: {
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent],
  },
  async setup(moduleOptions, nuxt) {
    const logger = useLogger(PACKAGE_NAME);

    nuxt.options.runtimeConfig = nuxt.options.runtimeConfig || {};

    const { intents } = moduleOptions;

    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);

    if (!process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN) {
      throw new Error("Discord Token must be set");
    }

    const client = useDiscord(intents!);

    /** If there is no pre-existing ready event we execute our own. */
    // if (isReady) {
    //   client.once(Events.ClientReady, () =>
    //     consola.success("Discord bot is ready and listening...")
    //   );
    // }

    client.once(Events.ClientReady, () =>
      logger.success("Discord bot is ready and listening...")
    );

    nuxt.hook("nitro:config", (nitroConfig) => {
      nitroConfig.alias = nitroConfig.alias || {};
      nitroConfig.externals = defu(
        typeof nitroConfig.externals === "object" ? nitroConfig.externals : {},
        { inline: [resolve("./runtime")] }
      );
      nitroConfig.alias["#discord"] = resolve("./runtime/server/utils");

      console.log(nitroConfig);
    });

    nuxt.hook("prepare:types", (options) => {
      const temp = addTemplate({
        filename: "types/discord.d.ts",
        getContents: () =>
          [
            "declare module '#discord' {",
            `  const defineDiscordEventHandler: typeof import('${resolve(
              "./runtime/server/utils"
            )}').defineDiscordEventHandler`,
            `  const useDiscord: typeof import('${resolve(
              "./runtime/server/utils"
            )}').useDiscord`,
            `  const DiscordService: typeof import('${resolve(
              "./runtime/server/utils"
            )}').DiscordService`,
            "}",
          ].join("\n"),
      }).dst;

      options.references.push({
        path: temp,
      });
    });

    const dir = resolve(nuxt.options.serverDir, "discord/events");
    const events = await new fdir()
      .glob("./**/*.js", "./**/*.ts", "./**/*.mjs")
      .withFullPaths()
      .withMaxDepth(1)
      .crawl(dir)
      .withPromise();

    if (events.length) {
      logger.info("Setting up events...");
      for (const event of events) {
        /** @vite-ignore */
        const e = await import(event);
        if (e.once) {
          client.once(e.name as any, (...args) => e.execute(...args));
        } else {
          client.on(e.name as any, (...args) => e.execute(...args));
        }
      }
    }

    nuxt.hook("ready", async () => {
      try {
        await client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
      }
    });

    nuxt.hook("close", () => client.destroy());
  },
});
```

```
<!--- ./server/discord/events/onReady.ts --->

import { Events } from "discord.js";
import  useCacheItem from "~/server/services/useCacheItem <-- also doesn't work.
import { defineDiscordEventHandler } from "#discord" <!-- doesn't work throws an error saying can't find #discord;

export default defineDiscordEventHandler(Events.ClientReady, true, async(client) => {
  const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
  console.log(guilds);
});
```

```
 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module '~/server/utils/useCacheItem'                                                                                                                                                                           11:22:49 p.m.
Require stack:
- /home/blackout/Projects/workplaces/nuxtApps/nuxt-bko/server/discord/events/interactionCreate.ts

  Require stack:
  - server/discord/events/onReady.ts
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
  at _resolve (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:241025)
  at jiti (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:243309)
  at server/discord/events/interactionCreate.ts:1:206
  at jiti (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:245784)
  at modules/discord/index.ts:121:65
  at async setup (modules/discord/index.ts:121:19)
  at async normalizedModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2140:18)
  at async installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2409:95)
  at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:3174:7)
  at async load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:204:9)
  at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:248:5)
  at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:48:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, nuxt module does not support alias import. You need to use relative path. modules are loaded before nuxt build process, with jiti, which does not support alias.

References:

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/11097
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/11914
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13728

### 2024-02-2 updates:

I wanted to share that I've found a temporary solution to the issue we've been experiencing with Nuxt 3 module aliases not being recognized due to the JIT environment's limitations with tsconfig.json. Understanding the impact this has on our development workflow, I've developed and published a package named [@anymud/nuxt-module-alias](https://github.com/anymud/nuxt-module-alias).

This package leverages the module-alias package to set up aliases at the very beginning of the Nuxt project. It aims to offer a seamless development experience by ensuring that TypeScript paths and aliases are correctly resolved, mirroring the expected behavior in a typical Nuxt 3 project setup.